# ReactJS Photo Gallery using an array of urls from Express database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gallery, photo

it's me again.. I'm kinda stuck (using ReactJS front end and nodeJS backend). I want to use the photo gallery component "react-photo-gallery" (looks lilke this https://codesandbox.io/s/o7o241q09?from-embed)

But I have a problem, i'm using an express database, and I have managed to get the img url when I upload the image in my site. I now have a table called "urlimages" with the column "urlimage". But here's the problem, the component uses an array with the following structure : [{src, width, height}, {src, width height}, etc]. I want to put one by one my URLs in the src. Is that doable?

Here's my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';
import Photo from './Photo';
import { SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove } from 'react-sortable-hoc';


const SortablePhoto = SortableElement(Photo);
const SortableGallery = SortableContainer(({photos}) => {
  return <Gallery photos={photos} ImageComponent={SortablePhoto}/>
});

class PhotoGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onSortEnd = this.onSortEnd.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      photos: photos,
      urlImages: []
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3004/getUrlImages');
    const newList = await response.json();
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      ...previousState,
      urlImages: newList,
     }));
  }
  onSortEnd ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
    this.setState({
      photos: arrayMove(this.state.photos, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SortableGallery axis={"xy"} photos={this.state.photos} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />
    )
  }
}
const photos = [
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599",
    width: 3,
    height: 3
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/iecJiKe_RNg/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/epcsn8Ed8kY/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/NQSWvyVRIJk/800x599",
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/zh7GEuORbUw/600x799",
    width: 3,
    height: 4
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/PpOHJezOalU/800x599",
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  },
  {
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/I1ASdgphUH4/800x599",
    width: 4,
    height: 3
  }
];
export default PhotoGallery;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I can succesfully get from my backend the url data with a fetch. But how would I manage putting each link into an array? I think I must use some mapping but I can't find how to do this.. Can anyone help a beginner? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the width and height of each?

Comment: I don't have, I can manage tho adding these to the database I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to convert your response 
 `[src, src, ...]` to `[{src, width, height}, {src, width, height}, ...]`

Not a big deal, you need to apply the `map()` function to your `this.state.urlImages` array. You could for example, define a function to perform this for you:

```
galleryPhotos() {
   if(this.state.urlImages) {
      return this.state.urlImages.map(function(urlImage) {
         return { src: urlImage, width: YOUR_WIDTH, height: YOUR_HEIGHT }
      })
   }
}
```

And pass this to your `SortableGallery` component as a `photos` prop.

```
<SortableGallery axis={"xy"} photos={this.galleryPhotos()} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />
```

**Note:** keep in mind that you still need a way to specify your `height` and `width` properties if you don't already have them for each image.

**UPDATE:**

@Mich's response data was an array of objects (each with a single property of "urlimage"), thus the last return statement of `galleryPhotos()` function should look like:

```
return { src: urlImage.urlimage, width: YOUR_WIDTH, height: YOUR_HEIGHT }
```

Comment: hey man, I've updated my original post. I think i'm on the way to understanding the concept and making it work. Then number of image is right (i have 4 urls in my database), but the image doesnt show (theres the little green logo). When I copy the URL of the image, it shows "http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]". I think the json isnt right somewhere.. could you help me ?

Comment: can you add a `debugger` under your  `const newList = await response.json();` and check how does your newList object look like?

Comment: yes I've ran a console.log, it shows me this : `Encountered two children with the same key, \`[object Object]\`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.`

Comment: here's my http://localhost:3004/getUrlImages


`[{"urlimage":"https://res.cloudinary.com/crystalis/image/upload/v1520782409/21912885_955286677962097_195385030_n_tppnmv.jpg"},{"urlimage":"https://res.cloudinary.com/crystalis/image/upload/v1520785046/21849395_955286681295430_1656537476_n_xgmwuw.jpg"},{"urlimage":"https://res.cloudinary.com/crystalis/image/upload/v1520785422/21849338_955286671295431_603717957_n_rumebi.jpg"},{"urlimage":"https://res.cloudinary.com/crystalis/image/upload/v1520787477/21935457_955286667962098_1181676938_n_oxp3pw.jpg"}]`

Comment: ok, so the response you are getting for the server is an array of objects (each object containing one property of `urlimage`). You just need to extract that property out of each of these objects and pass it to the new array.
Change the last return statement of my `galleryPhotos` function to `return { src: urlImage.urlimage, width: YOUR_WIDTH, height: YOUR_HEIGHT }`

Comment: oh my god man it's working now I get it :) thanks so much for your help I appreciate it